# Is there a way to replace some javascript variables (at build time?) with some DEV or RELEASE config data?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core

I have a really simple website (ASP.NET core) that is a single `.html` static page and 6 `.js` files.

In one of the js files are some data that is based on my configuration:

- `localhost`
- `dev`
- `production`

right now, it's hardcoded for my `localhost`.

Is there way that I can build/package the simple app so that if i say `dev` or `prod` in some command line arg, it replaces those values with something from somewhere else?

eg.

in `main.js`:

```
var environment = "localhost";
var rooturl = "https://localhost:43210";
```

and lets imagine i wish to build to my dev server...

```
var environment = "dev";
var rooturl = "https://pewpew.azurewebsites.com";
```

Is this possible? To keep things simple, assume I know *nothing* of JS tools and processes. (it's actually the truth, but lets not tell anyone that).

Update (further clarifications):

with 1x static html file and 6x static JS files, I have a static website. So i'm hoping to generate the js files as static files (still) but with the *environment data* already compiled in it.

Comment: what I do is pass some variables via data- attributes in html in the view which can come from config and be environment specific. the js can then retrieve the values from the html attributes instead of hard coded in the js

Comment: You could do that with a simple script and a regex replace in any language under the sun, no JS knowledge required. I typically use a combination of good ole `make` and `tr` for stuff like that. Stuff that's older than I am. EDIT: just saw you tagged this with asp.net. Oops.

Answer (score 0):

you can use some build tools like [grunt](https://gruntjs.com/). where you can define build task which takes the environment parameter and change the variables to the desired values.

another (more simple) way is to dynamicaly create main.js (with dependency on the environment) file with your backend and the frontend will load it when it starts. src of the script tag can be the asp script, where the output is javascript

Answer (score 0):

This is a snippet from a project in which I do just that. I replace various place holders with values stored in the environment variables.

This example is based on a linux environment, so I used `sed` to modify the file in-place, however you could just as easily read the file into memory, do the replace and write it back to disk.

```
grunt.task.registerTask('secretkeys', 'Replace various keys', function() {
    var oauth;
    try{
        oauth = JSON.parse(process.env.oauthKeys).oauth;
    }
    catch(e){
        oauth = {google:{}};
    }
    var replaces = {
        '==GOOGLECLIENTID==':oauth.google.client_id || '{**GOOGLECLIENTID**}',
        '==GOOGLESECRETKEY==':oauth.google.client_secret || '{**GOOGLESECRETKEY**}',
        '==SECRETKEY==':oauth.secret || '{**SECRETKEY**}',
        '==LOCALAUTH==':oauth.login,
    };
    const child = require('child_process');
    grunt.file.expand('bin/**/*.json').forEach(function(file) {
        grunt.log.write(`${file} \n`);
        for(var key in replaces){
            var cmd = 'sed -i s~{{orig}}~{{new}}~g {{file}}'
                .replace(/{{file}}/g,file)
                .replace(/{{orig}}/g,key.replace(/~/g,'\\~'))
                .replace(/{{new}}/g,replaces[key].replace(/~/g,'\\~'))
                ;
            grunt.log.write(` - ${key} \n`);
            //grunt.log.write(` ${cmd} \n`);
            child.execSync(cmd);
        }
    });
});
```

Hopefully you can modify to your purposes.

*EDIT* : I am reconsidering my answer, you are modifying javascript on a windows environment. You are likely better using PowerShell

```
(gc script.js) `
    .replace("==GOOGLECLIENTID==",$Env:GoogleClientId) `
    .replace("==SECRETKEY==",$Env:SecretKey) `
    > script-build.js
```

Comment: Okay ... but either using `PS` or `sed` .. these are all handled how? as part of `grunt`? so this means i need to learn grunt and see how to put that into my (non exists) build process?

Comment: Or, as my edit suggests, use Powershell to be your build process (the Powershell is a oneliner). If you don't want a build process, see my other answer.

Answer (score 0):

So after re-reading your question, I realize there is a better solution that I have used in the past. My other answer is still relevant, so I'll leave it.

It may be simplest to just create a config file in the same folder.

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="config.js" ></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="myscript.js" ></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  ask me your questions, bridgekeeper
 </body>
</html>
```

config.js

```
var config = {
    'colour': 'yellow'
};
```

myscript.js

```
var user = prompt("What is your favourite colour?", "");
if(user !== config.colour){
    alert("No BLUE! Ahhh....");
}
else{
    alert("You may pass");
}
```

This is the technique I use when developing simple HTA apps for use around the office.

Answer (score 0):

Check out envify. You can run it from the command line. https://github.com/hughsk/envify

`sudo npm install -g envify`

Say you have

```
var myVar = process.env.MYVAR;
```

Run from the command line

`MYVAR=somevalue envify input.js > output.js`

and the output js file should have

`var myVar = 'somevalue';`